# Is there a way to inject the hibernate filter methods while testing?

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, grails, hibernate-filters

I am using hibernate filter plugin in a Grails 2.2.5 project.

My controller contains code like this:

```
MyDomain.withoutHibernateFilter('myFilter'){ ... }
```

The method withoutHibernateFilter is injected by the plugin at runtime but is there any way to inject these methods to the domain class also while unit testing in Grails?